# Parsing JSON output to HTML Table

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have some problem to parse my json file to html table
this is url json file

https://sicantikws.layanan.go.id/api/TemplateData/keluaran/15141.json

i want to ask how to solved this problem, i wrote a code like this

```html
<?php
 $url = 'https://sicantikws.layanan.go.id/api/TemplateData/keluaran/15141.json';
 $response = file_get_contents($url);
 $responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
?>
<?php if($responseArray['success'] === 'true'|['message'] === ''): ?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach($headers as $h): ?>
            <th><?php echo $h; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($responseArray['data'] as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($row as $value); ?>
                <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your response is like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "",
"data": {
    "data2": array {
        array{},
        array{},
        array{}
     }
   }
}
```

Try this:

```
<?php foreach($responseArray['data']['data2'] as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($row as $value): ?>
            <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```